# (PHP): Testing models with Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, zend-test

When I run my PHP unit test I get:

```
1) Test_Model_Mapper_TestTest::testTest
Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_DefaultTableIterator::__construct() must be an array, null given, called in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/DataSet/AbstractXmlDataSet.php on line 134 and defined

/var/www/kosheroven/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Db/Operation/Truncate.php:73
/var/www/kosheroven/tests/ModelTestCase.php:79
/var/www/kosheroven/tests/application/models/mappers/TestTest.php:33
```

Expected result is for the test to pass, obviously. By sprinkling around a few echoes I discovered that this is caused from within the parent::setUp() call, but I have no idea why. I am completely stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// /tests/ModelTestCase.php

abstract class Test_ModelTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase
{
    public $application;
    protected $_db;
    protected $_model;
    protected $_modelClass;
    protected $_filesDir;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->application = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
        );

        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');

        $this->_filesDir  = dirname(__FILE__) . '/files/';
        $this->_filesDir .= str_replace('_', '/', get_class($this));
        $this->_model     = new $this->_modelClass();
        // echo '123'; is printed
        parent::setUp();
        // echo '456'; is not
    }

    public function appBootstrap()
    {
        $this->application->bootstrap();
    }

    protected function getConnection()
    {
        if(empty($this->_db))
        {
            $options = $this->application->getOptions();
            $schema = $options['resources']['db']['params']['dbname'];
            $db = $this->application->getBootstrap()->getPluginResource('db')
                    ->getDbAdapter();

            $this->_db = $this->createZendDbConnection($db, $schema);
        }

        return $this->_db;
    }

    protected function getDataSet()
    {
        return $this->createXmlDataSet(dirname(__FILE__) . '/files/seed.xml');
    }
}

// /tests/Model/Mapper/TestTest.php

class Test_Model_Mapper_TestTest extends Test_ModelTestCase
{
    protected $_modelClass = 'Application_Model_Mapper_Ingredients';

    public function testTest()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will help you, but the problem may be with:
`$this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');`

You see $bootstrap property does not exist in Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase, unlike for Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase. So I think that your bootstrap method is not called.

Thus you could try to replace line `$this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');` with `$this->appBootstrap();`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. The reason here was, that the XML fixture was generated by MySQLDump and missing the `<database name="xyz">` node. This turned $this->tables in PHPUnit into NULL instead Array.

Answer (score 0):

Full solution and code at http://www.unexpectedit.com/zend-php/testing-database-model-with-phpunit-on-zend-studio

**Edit application/configs/application.ini**

```
[testing : production]
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = 127.0.0.1
resources.db.params.port = 8889
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = root
resources.db.params.dbname = "test_myproject_com"
xmlseeds.folder = APPLICATION_PATH "/../tests/xmlseeds/"
```

**Create folders and file MyProject/library/Application/Test/PHPUnit/DatabaseTestCase/Abstract.php**

**Create folders and file MyProject/tests/application/models/ProjectTest.php**

**Create files /tests/xmlseeds/*.xml**

I. Pascual www.unexpectedit.com